# Kafka Producer - Just need some direction

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-kafka

I'm working with Kafka for the first time. I've set up confluent cloud locally, created topics along with some JDBC connectors to populate the topics with data. Now, I want to try to trigger a connector from my Java application. The gist is that we have a large data feed that we want to run only once a day, triggered by an existing Java application. I already have the topic, database tables, and a JDBC connector with a custom query. This all works fine, produces the data I want and I can see it in coming in via the CLI but now I need to trigger the pull from java - is this scenario possible with Kafka?

Answer (score 1):

The JDBC Kafka source connector is meant to be ran continuously, but if you want to "trigger" it, that would be an HTTP client to make a POST request with `mode=bulk`, or incrementing / timestamp to get only the data you added, and a large `poll.interval.ms` if using `bulk` to prevent reading the table multiple times.  You'd add your `query` there too.

You then would somehow need to know when the connector started its tasks finished reading the data, then you would issue an HTTP DELETE to stop the sourcing of the database.

Or rather than deleting the connector, you can set the poll interval to a day and leave it alone and just have your database client insert the data as needed. You will still want to monitor if the connector is actually successful on each day.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to do the following.

On a trigger, you want to pull data from a database using JDBC and push the those data to kafka. If this is your requirement following is one solution i can propose.

Kafka producer is something that you can create by your own easily. In fact your your Java code that pulls data from databse itself can act as kafka producer also.

You are connecting to database and pulling data using a library. Similarly there are libraries that allows to connect to Kafka directly from java code. You can use these library along with your Java code to push data to the kafka topics. And when your java code is able to push data to a kafka topics , that itself make your java code as kafka producer.

Following is one example that you can refer for creating kafka producer: https://dzone.com/articles/kafka-producer-and-consumer-example

The solution I proposed is depicted over a simple diagram below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this! I'll dig in to the example. I was also investigating REST APIs to trigger a producer

Comment: how to control this java app externally, like a start/stop/resume?